# Call multiple DELETE calls from a single POST call in express?

Tags: express, json-server

I am using json-server(based on express) and gulp-json-srv in a project. I have the following "customRoute":

```
'/deletefavorites': {
    method: 'POST',
    handler: function(req, res, next) {
        req.method = 'DELETE';
        var arr = req.body;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            req.url = '/favorites/' + arr[i];
            res.redirect(req.url);
        }
    }
}
```

The array req.body simply holds ids of "favorites". So the req.body looks something like this:

```
{[
    "id": "123",
    "id":"124",
    ...
]}
```

The problem is that redirect only redirects this request once and then errors. Meaning I would only be able to DELETE one record, and it also doesn't handle the "method", because I can only send the URL in a redirect.

What I would want is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    req.url = '/favorites/' + arr[i];
    app.handle(req, res, next);
}    
next();
```

With the new parameters. Is something like that possible? I've searched through many related stack overflow questions, but the only solution I found was using a xhr request in there, but I figured express should have a way to deal with this?

Comment: Why you want this to happen through the URL? That approach is wrong if it is not a inter-service call. If you are within the same service then you should have a re-usable logic for delete which is either called on all the ids one by one or you should have a logic where you can send an array of ids and delete them. Then you should call the directly in your `/deletefavorites` handler

Comment: Hey @TarunLalwani, if that was an option we would of course do it like that. It would take more than 500 characters to explain the architecture behind our project. Basically our javascript logic is shared with the javascript logic of an AEM project. And on that AEM project it is more "beautiful" to have a single post call with multiple ids than having 10 single DELETE calls, which would increase the load to a server by a lot. So that is why we need to "translate" the post call to single delete calls on our prototype

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168062/discussion-call-multiple-delete-calls-from-a-single-post-call-in-express) room for further discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example way of calling within the service

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const request = require('request');

app.post('/deleteFavorites', (req, res) => {
    req.body = [
        {"id": "123"},
        {"id":"124"},
    ]

    console.log("deleteFavorites was called?")
    request.delete({
        url: "http://" + req.headers.host + "/favorites/delete",
        body: req.body,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body, error, response);
        res.status(200).send("all good");
    });

});

app.delete('/favorites/delete', (req, res) => {
    console.log("favorites/delete was called?")
    res.status(200).send("all good");

});

app.listen(9090);
```

The ideal way is to do it through re-usable functions but since you mentioned that is not an option, this is another possible approach one can use.

But I would recommend to limit it to one call instead of multiple calls, else you may cause a request explosion at the server. If you send 100 ids at server in `/deleteFavorites` then that would raise too may request at server causing most of them to timeout